# Change in Singular Value Decomposition of a matrix on addition of a single row

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

Given that I know the svd decomposition of a matrix, is there any way to compute the svd decomposition of the matrix obtained by adding a single row to the original matrix? Is there any relation between the 2 decompositions?

Comment: You might have a look on [this paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0613061).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Thanks for the link! I'll go through it :)